# Calculate like DISTRIB.BINOM

Tags: binomial-distribution

I have a formula in excel : 
=1-DISTRIB.BINOM( 7;10; 0.5; 1 )

Result : 0,0546875

is possibile to calculate manually? how?

Answer (score 1):

It is:
$$1-BINOM.DIST(7,10,0.5,1)=\\f(8)+f(9)+f(10)=\\C_8^{10}(0.5)^8(0.5)^2+C_9^{10}(0.5)^9(0.5)^1+C_{10}^{10}(0.5)^{10}(0.5)^0=\\ \frac{1}{2^{10}}\left(45+10+1\right)=\frac{56}{1024}=0.0546875.$$